Configure log4net programatically using log4net.Ext.Json
I have an application that uses log4net to perform logging.  Because it is a requirement that the user can set the logging level I have configured it programatically.
        private static Dictionary<CommandStationSettings.LogLevels, Level> _lookup = new Dictionary<CommandStationSettings.LogLevels, Level>
        {
            { CommandStationSettings.LogLevels.Debug, Level.Debug },
            { CommandStationSettings.LogLevels.Info, Level.Info },
            { CommandStationSettings.LogLevels.Warning, Level.Warn },
            { CommandStationSettings.LogLevels.Error, Level.Error },
        };

        public static void Setup(string path, CommandStationSettings.LogLevels level = CommandStationSettings.LogLevels.Info)
        {
            Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

            PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout
            {
                ConversionPattern = "%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - %message%newline",
                Footer = Environment.NewLine,
                Header = Environment.NewLine
            };
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

            RollingFileAppender roller = new RollingFileAppender
            {
                AppendToFile = true,
                File = path,
                Layout = patternLayout,
                MaxSizeRollBackups = 10,
                MaximumFileSize = "10MB",
                RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size,
                StaticLogFileName = true
            };
            roller.ActivateOptions();
            hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller);

            MemoryAppender memory = new MemoryAppender();
            memory.ActivateOptions();
            hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(memory);

            hierarchy.Root.Level = _lookup[level];
            hierarchy.Configured = true;
        }


I now have a new requirement to log using json, so I would like to add a new RollingFileAppended with a JsonPatternConverter but cannot find any examples of how to do this.
Basically rewrite the following programatically
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoding value="UTF-8" type="System.Text.UTF8Encoding" />
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Logs\WcfLibrary.log" name ="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <countDirection value="-1"/>
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <logName value="Myapp" />
    <applicationName value="BmwService" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
      <member value="logDateTime%date:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ffff" />
      <decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
      <member value="hostName" />
      <default />
      <remove value="date" />
      <remove value="ndc" />
      <remove value="message" />
      <remove value="thread" />
      <remove value="exception" />
      <member value="logData:messageObject" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="All"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>

The log4net.ext.json nuget package website only has examples as above so I'm really stuck as to how to progress.
I'm guessing I need to create a PatternLayout using JsonPatternConverter but there is no documentation for this class.
